# why is grails returning me an array of null objects?

Tags: grails, groovy

From my `create.gsp` page, I expect to see a list of all the `districts` available on my database.

```
<td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: streamInstance, field: 'district', 'errors')}">
    <% println  ctv.District.list(); %> 
    <g:select name="district.id" from="${ctv.District.list()}" optionKey="id" value="${streamInstance?.district?.id}"  />
</td>
```

However, I see the `<select>` statement not empty, but unable to see any name. When I added the `println`, I see:

```
    District = [
              null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
              null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
              null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
              null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
              null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
              null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 
              null, null, null, null, null, null
   ]
```

I have no idea why is `District` an array of `null` objects. I was expecting to see the `district names`. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is `ctv` variable? Does it have `District` property? Did you name any property starting with a capital letter?

Comment: `ctv` is the package name, `District` is the Domain name. I don't have any property starting with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure they're null? Or is the `toString()` method returning `null` or `"null"`?

Comment: I have a `public String toString(){
  name
 }` in the `Stream` class, but that's not the reason

Comment: How do you know that? What about trying `println ctv.District.list().collect{ it ? "(name: $it.name, id: $it.id)" : "N00LL" }`?

Comment: @VictorSergienko Yes, now I'm able to see the values `(name : <name>, id : <id> )`. How can I modify my code in other to be able to show the  `name` field?

Comment: I'd see if `name` is a regular field and if it's set. If it's a more complex accessor, then it might be its logic broken; Burt's assumption that it's likely a broken `toString()` was the most probable, `getName()` is the next suspect :) BTW try `optionValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps modify District? Assuming it is a domain object and you are in dev mode grails would have reset any custom loading of the in memory data. Restarting would likely solve the problem in that case.

Comment: Michael, the domain object it's fine ... I don't know why I'm getting those `null` objects. Just for curiosity, the number of `null` objects in the array is equal to the number of `Districts`.